# Power Query to Convert List of Links to Grid of Crossings

Tags: powerquery, m

In Excel I have a data table of Paired Items that are tagged with an identifier.  Essentially, named linkages.

Worksheet: **Links**

| Tag | Point-A | Point-B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Route 1 | Home | Office |
| Route 2 | Home | Grocery 1 |
| Happy Hour | Office | Bar |
| Sad Hour | Office | Dump |
| Headaches | Bar | Pharmacy |
| Sick | Bar | Dump |
| Route 3 | Office | Moms |
| Route 4 | Office | Park |
| Victory | Park | Bar |
| Discard | Park | Dump |

I want to transform this data into a grid of all points in rows and columns with the tag placed at the intersection (Much like old paper road maps with grids for city distances)

Worksheet: **Grid**

| A \ B | Bar | Dump | Grocery 1 | Home | Home | Moms | Office | Office | Park | Pharmacy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bar |  | Sick |  |  |  |  | Happy Hour |  | Victory | Headaches |
| Dump | Sick |  |  |  |  |  | Sad Hour |  | Discard |  |
| Grocery 1 |  |  |  |  | Route 2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Home |  |  |  |  |  |  | Route 1 |  |  |  |
| Home |  |  | Route 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Moms |  |  |  |  |  |  | Route 3 |  |  |  |
| Office | Happy Hour | Sad Hour |  | Route 1 |  | Route 3 |  |  |  |  |
| Office |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Route 4 |  |
| Park | Victory | Discard |  |  |  |  |  | Route 4 |  |  |
| Pharmacy | Headaches |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I have written the following `M` code for transforming, but it seems a bit wayward and overwrought.  I am using bit coding of points to construct a join key, so the bitting process will probably break around 32 points.

Is there a shorter set of `LET`s that do the same transform to grid ?

Is there a way to create a key that is `Min(Point-A,Point-B)` delimited concatenation with `Max(Point-A,Point-B)`, and thus not rely of *bitting*?

**M** code (copied from Advanced Editor)

```
let
    LinksTable = Table.SelectRows(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(), each [Name] = "Links"),
    Links = Table.RemoveColumns(Table.ExpandTableColumn(LinksTable, "Content", {"Tag", "Point-A", "Point-B"}), "Name"),
    AllPoints = Table.Combine(
    { Table.SelectColumns(Table.RenameColumns(Links,{"Point-A", "Point"}), "Point"),
      Table.SelectColumns(Table.RenameColumns(Links,{"Point-B", "Point"}), "Point")
    }),
    ThePoints = Table.Sort(Table.Distinct(AllPoints),{"Point"}),
    PointsIndexed = Table.AddIndexColumn(ThePoints, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    PointsBitted = Table.RemoveColumns(Table.AddColumn(PointsIndexed, "Bit", each Number.Power(2, [Index]), Int64.Type),"Index"),
    AllPairsBitted = Table.Join(
      Table.RenameColumns(PointsBitted, {{"Point", "Point-A"}, {"Bit", "Bit-A"}}), {},
      Table.RenameColumns(PointsBitted, {{"Point", "Point-B"}, {"Bit", "Bit-B"}}), {},
      JoinKind.FullOuter
    ),
    AllPairsKeyed = Table.RemoveColumns(
      Table.AddColumn(AllPairsBitted, "BitKeyPair", each Number.BitwiseOr([#"Bit-A"],[#"Bit-B"])),
      { "Bit-A", "Bit-B"}
    ),    
    #"Links-A-Bitted" = Table.Join(
    Links, "Point-A",
    Table.RenameColumns(PointsBitted,{{"Point", "Point-A"}, {"Bit", "Bit-A"}}), "Point-A"
  ),
    #"Links-AB-Bitted" = Table.Join(
    #"Links-A-Bitted", "Point-B",
    Table.RenameColumns(PointsBitted,{{"Point", "Point-B"}, {"Bit", "Bit-B"}}), "Point-B"
  ),
    LinksKeyed = Table.RemoveColumns(
      Table.AddColumn(#"Links-AB-Bitted", "BitKeyLink", each Number.BitwiseOr([#"Bit-A"],[#"Bit-B"])),
      { "Bit-A", "Bit-B"}
    ),
    AllPairsTagged = Table.Sort( Table.RemoveColumns(
    Table.Join(
      AllPairsKeyed, "BitKeyPair",
      Table.SelectColumns(LinksKeyed, {"BitKeyLink", "Tag"}), "BitKeyLink",
      JoinKind.LeftOuter
    ),
    {"BitKeyPair", "BitKeyLink"}
  ),
  {"Point-A", "Point-B"}
),
    Grid = Table.Pivot(AllPairsTagged, List.Distinct(AllPairsTagged[#"Point-B"]), "Point-B", "Tag", List.First)
in
    Grid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `PIVOT` to achieve this. Using directly this functionality would not work because you are looking for symmetry of columns and rows.

The trick is to force that symmetry, appending values from `Point-B` into values of `Point-A`.

### Steps

1. Create a secondary table and reorder the columns in the opposite way that the original table, so `Tag`, `Point-B` and `Point-A`.
2. On the secondary table, rename the columns to `Tag`, `Point-A` and `Point-B` in that order. `Append` usually take column names literally, so without renaming it would append the names of the same columns.
3. `Pivot` on column `Point-B` without aggregating data.
4. Reorder the columns using `Point-A` as a reference, so you have symmetry of columns and rows.

It's worth mentioning that's good practice to `Buffer` the source table because is used multiple times across the calculations.

### Calculation

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("Zc69CsMgEMDxVwnOLv14ghKoS2looEvIcJwXIkEMZxx8+6axiUInwd/99bpOvFxYqDoJKZSztB7PYTBIope7nbPd2SFxXMe/rGCeY6Vc4JxJcQPetAX9Z3Wwc0oJNOBI/hdI0YzAFjCm1uB0yBGldS7lgw9nfWHX0hrgabO3wcVx3K/yirXxCKwzpK/6Dw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Tag = _t, #"Point-A" = _t, #"Point-B" = _t]),
    BufferedSource = Table.Buffer(Source),
    SecondTable = Table.ReorderColumns(BufferedSource,{"Tag","Point-B","Point-A"}),
    SecondTableRenameCols = Table.RenameColumns(SecondTable,{{"Point-A","Point-B"},{"Point-B","Point-A"}}),
    AppendTables = Table.Combine({BufferedSource,SecondTableRenameCols}),
    PivotTables = Table.Pivot(AppendTables, List.Distinct(AppendTables[#"Point-B"]), "Point-B", "Tag"),
    ReorderCols = Table.ReorderColumns( PivotTables, PivotTables[#"Point-A"])

in ReorderCols
```

### Output

| Point-A | Bar | Dump | Grocery 1 | Home | Moms | Office | Park | Pharmacy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bar |  | Sick |  |  |  | Happy Hour | Victory | Headaches |
| Dump | Sick |  |  |  |  | Sad Hour | Discard |  |
| Grocery 1 |  |  |  | Route 2 |  |  |  |  |
| Home |  |  | Route 2 |  |  | Route 1 |  |  |
| Moms |  |  |  |  |  | Route 3 |  |  |
| Office | Happy Hour | Sad Hour |  | Route 1 | Route 3 |  | Route 4 |  |
| Park | Victory | Discard |  |  |  | Route 4 |  |  |
| Pharmacy | Headaches |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Can you explain how you created the value for `Binary.FromText` that is the table data?

Comment: That's coming from the `Enter Data` feature, just to mimic your dataset. You can change that to your original source.